# How to delete container use containerd ctr?

Tags: docker, containers, containerd

I use `sudo ctr container run ...` to run a container. But there are something wrong with the process in my container. So I suppose that there is no task is running. I use `sudo ctr task ls`, it shows,

```
TASK         PID    STATUS
test    0      CREATED
```

Then I want to kill it with `sudo ctr task kill test`. However, it shows that

```
ctr: process not started: unknown
```

Then I use `sudo ctr task delete test`. It also shows errors,

```
ctr: task must be stopped before deletion: created: failed precondition
```

I don't know how to delete this container. Once I delete this container, it comes with `ctr: task must be stopped before deletion: created: failed precondition`. How can I delete this container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way.

```
ps aux | grep shim
sudo kill -9 <pid of your process>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge. Turns out in containerd ctr, tasks and containers are different things. According to [this blogpost](https://blog.mobyproject.org/getting-started-with-containerd-a81fa090982f), a container is a metadata object that resources are allocated and attached to while a task is a running process in the system.

So, to answer your question, you can simply remove/delete the container by:

```
ctr container delete test
```

You can substitute delete with either `del`, `remove` or `rm`. They all do the same thing. That should get rid of your error